# Download a pandas df with images into word document using python

Tags: python, pandas, image

Hi I am creating a dataframe with pandas in python that is going to include pictures with the following code (the image is already downloaded into my working directory)

```
#Create the df using pandas
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import Image, HTML

row_1 = ["Bob", '<img src="bob.jfif" width="60">',"Red"]
df = pd.DataFrame(row_1).transpose()
df.columns = ['Name', 'Picture','Fav.color']
HTML(df.to_html(escape=False))
```

And so it looks alright inside my jupyter notebook

[image]

But when I try to download this pandas df into a word document using the following code

```
#Export into word document
import docx

#Create new document
doc = docx.Document()

# add a table to the end and create a reference variable
# extra row is so we can add the header row
t = doc.add_table(rows=df.shape[0]+1, cols=df.shape[1]) #+1 allegedly for the header

# add the header rows.
for j in range(df.shape[-1]):
    t.cell(0,j).text = df.columns[j]

# add the rest of the data frame
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for j in range(df.shape[-1]):
        t.cell(i+1,j).text = str(df.values[i,j])

# save the doc
doc.save('test.docx')
```

When I open the word document the image is not able to show

[image]

Is there any way to get the pictures inside the word document table either by directly downloading from source URL or importing from my downloaded pictures in working directory? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shld be because the HTML code for the image (`<img src="bob.jfif" width="60">`) is not directly supported in a Word document. So, to include images in word document, you may use the `python-docx` library along with `Pillow` for the processing of images.

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
from PIL import Image
# Create DF
row_1 = ["Bob", "bob.jfif", "Red"]
df = pd.DataFrame([row_1], columns=['Name', 'Picture', 'Fav.color'])
# Create new doc
doc = Document()
# Add a table to the end and create a reff var
t = doc.add_table(rows=df.shape[0]+1, cols=df.shape[1])
# Add the header rows
for j in range(df.shape[-1]):
   t.cell(0, j).text = df.columns[j]
# Add the rest of the df
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
   for j in range(df.shape[-1]):
       if j == 1:  # Assuming the image path is in the second column
           img_path = df.values[i, j]
           cell = t.cell(i+1, j)
           # Resize the image to fit in the cell
           img = Image.open(img_path)
           img.thumbnail((60, 60))
           # Add the image to the cell
           cell.clear()  # Clear existing content
           paragraph = cell.add_paragraph()
           run = paragraph.add_run()
           run.add_picture(img_path, width=Inches(1.25))  # Adjust width 
       else:
           t.cell(i+1, j).text = str(df.values[i, j])
# Save the doc
doc.save('test.docx')
```

Rmb to adjust the image path according to your DF structure. For this example, i assume the image path is in the second column (`j == 1`).

The `Pillow` library is used to resize the image, and `cell._element.clear_content()` is used to clear the default text content of the cell before adding the image.

Give it a try !

Comment: Is there something wrong with the ```run = cell.paragraphs[0].add_run()``` line I get the list index out of range error

Comment: It might be an issue with the cell structure. Let me edit the code to ensure the cell contains a paragraph before attempting to add a run @Jeff238